# Can not serialise Expando Object - expando object does not implement add(system.object)

Tags: c#, serialization, expandoobject

Hi I am creating a list of Expando objects and passing it to serialise and I get this error -
To be xml serializable types which inherit from ienumerable must have an implementation of add ,system.dynamic.expando object does not implement add(system.object).

I have searched through similar questions - but I am not allowed to change anything on the serialiser....

Is there any other way ?

Comment: I have tried to create a subclass from Expando object to add Add method but Expando object can't be subclassed

Answer (score 0):

You can derive from `DynamicObject` and implement the `IXmlSerializable`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var filePath = @"c:\1.xml";
        dynamic expando = new SerilaizableExpandoObject();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SerilaizableExpandoObject));

        expando.Name = "Anindya";
        expando.StackOverflowReputation = 100;

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath)) {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, expando);
        }

        expando = (SerilaizableExpandoObject)serializer.Deserialize(File.OpenRead(filePath));
        Console.WriteLine(expando.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(expando.StackOverflowReputation);
    }
}

public class SerilaizableExpandoObject : DynamicObject, IXmlSerializable, IDictionary<string, object>
{
    private readonly string root = "SerilaizableExpandoObject";
    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> expando = null;

    public SerilaizableExpandoObject() {
        expando = new ExpandoObject();
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
        object value;

        if (expando.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out value)) {
            result = value;
            return true;
        }

        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
        expando[binder.Name] = value;

        return true;
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) {
        reader.ReadStartElement(root);

        while (!reader.Name.Equals(root)) {
            object value;
            string typeContent;
            Type underlyingType;
            var name = reader.Name;

            reader.MoveToAttribute("type");
            typeContent = reader.ReadContentAsString();
            underlyingType = Type.GetType(typeContent);
            reader.MoveToContent();
            expando[name] = reader.ReadElementContentAs(underlyingType, null);
        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
        foreach (var key in expando.Keys) {
            var value = expando[key];

            writer.WriteStartElement(key);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", value.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
            writer.WriteString(value.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }

    public void Add(string key, object value) {
        expando.Add(key, value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key) {
        return expando.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public ICollection<string> Keys {
        get { return expando.Keys; }
    }

    public bool Remove(string key) {
        return expando.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out object value) {
        return expando.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public ICollection<object> Values {
        get { return expando.Values; }
    }

    public object this[string key] {
        get {
            return expando[key];
        }
        set {
            expando[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item) {
        expando.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear() {
        expando.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item) {
        return expando.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex) {
        expando.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count {
        get { return expando.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly {
        get { return expando.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item) {
        return expando.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetEnumerator() {
        return expando.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am casting the ExpandoObject into Dictionary .. This SerilaizableExpandoObject can not be cast into Dictionary ...

Comment: why do you need to cast it into Dictionary?

Comment: Because I am creating dynamic property  names - prefixing each property name  from a strongly typed object

Comment: So why do you need an ExpandoObject? Just use a Dictionary.

Comment: I've changed my example to support casting to IDictionary<string, object>